# Where should I open initial dialogs in an Eclipse application?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have an Eclipse RCP application.  When the application is started I want to immediately present the user with a login dialog.  Where is the best place to do this?

I've tried to use various hooks in the WorkbenchAdvisor and WorkbenchWindowAdvisor, but all of these open a dialog before the application had a task bar icon.  In this case the dialog can easily be moved behind other windows and there will be no visual indication that the application is open, and the user might open several instances of the application by mistake.

I could force the dialog to be on top, but that's not a good solution.  I want a proper modal dialog.  A good example of such a dialog is Firefox's "save page as" dialog.  When this dialog is present it is always in front of the main browser window; you must complete or close the dialog before you can effectively resume browsing the web.  However, this "save page as" dialog doesn't force itself to be on top of every window, just the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: Is it allowed to have multiple instances open? If not, you have to implement independent from the Login-Dialog-Problem something that prevents opening several instance. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104304/eclipse-rcp-how-to-prevent-multiple-instances-of-rcp-from-launching) (btw: I made good experiences with the server-socket thing).
Second: If you overwrite `#postWindowOpen` in your `ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor` the application is up and running (including task-item). The only drawback is that your views are already opened, you have to reload them after a successful login.

Comment: Yes, I ended up overriding postWindowOpen of WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a splash screen your login dialog: see an example [here](http://tom-eclipse-dev.blogspot.com/2007/06/splash-screen-and-threads.html).